# R - Avoiding for loops based on matrix indices

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I would like to know if it's possible to do the following trick avoiding `for` loops maybe using smoehow `apply`, but I dunno how to do in this case with that `max(i-4,1)`

```
x <- matrix(seq_len(100),10,10)
x[,1] <- letters[1:10] 
y <- x
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  for (j in 2:ncol(x)) {
    y[i,j] <- x[max(i-4,1),j]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Lag a variable? And how is this avoiding the `for` loop?

Comment: yes, it should be a lag but also `0.5*(x[i,j]+x[max(i-4,1),j])`. I was trying to use `apply` but I dunno how to use it when based on a matrix index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like a simple lagging function here is one that works for data.tables and data frames. I'm certain you can edit to work with matrices.

```
#data table version
lagging<-
function (data, var, time) 
{
    return(c(rep(NA, time), head(data[, eval(as.name(var))], 
        (length(data[, eval(as.name(var))]) - time))))
}

#data frame version
lagging<-
function (data, var, time) 
{
    return(c(rep(NA, time), head(data[, var], 
        (length(data[, var]) - time))))
}
```

Comment: Ok, I try to see how to adapt it for my case. However, you can confirm there's not a way to do using based functions. It was my worry

Comment: I can neither confirm nor deny ;)